# Does rails do a rollback if I use begin...rescue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, transactions

I'd like to add a begin...rescue block to one of my controllers create method, in order to log better info and construct the correct error message to return to the client. Does the rescue in any way 'interrupt' the rollback process?

I'm assuming rails automatically does a rollback.  When does it happen? Has it already happened by the time I get in the rescue clause?

I'm using mySQL on Dreamhost and I think they use innoDB.

Comment: Please take a look in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329877/render-failing-to-render-correct-template-in-rescue-from-activerecordrollback/35731832#35731832

Answer (score 29):

I've been experimenting with this. It seems like if your rescue catches the exception that would have caused the rollback, the part of the transaction that already happened gets committed. In my case, I want the database rolled back to the way it was before the transaction started, but I still want to handle the exception.

I ended up with this:

```
self.transaction do
  first_operation
  begin
    operation_that_might_violate_db_constraint
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
      #deal with the error
      raise ActiveRecord::Rollback #force a rollback
  end
end
```

The `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` part makes sure the transaction gets completely rolled back. Without it, the changes from `first_operation` would end up getting committed.

The ActiveRecord::Rollback is a special kind of exception that doesn't bubble above the level of the transaction, so you won't end up with an uncaught exception that renders the error page.

I'm not sure this is the gold-standard way of doing this, but it seems to work.

Comment: be aware that if you catch the exception inside the transaction block and you want to do something in the rescue like sending an email, it will fail because of the transaction preventing it.

Answer (score 1):

Just using `begin`...`rescue` isn't enough to rollback a transaction.  You need to use:

```
ModelName.transaction do 
end
```

This is done explicitely on a call to save, so that all of your callbacks are executed together.  What exceptions are you catching in your rescue block?  What are you responding to?  What kind of errors?

Comment: I'm getting deadlocks. I don't think I'll have enough space here to describe it. It's for a card game. But in an after_save callback method for my PlayerAction model, I create another PlayerAction instance. I'm getting deadlocks on their related models. When that happens, I want to rollback the whole thing, including the first PlayerAction model and its relationships that were created.
Sounds like you're saying that rails does NOT do automatic transactions, is that right? I have to explicitly start them and trigger a rollback? Is there a resource somewhere for this? I've been searching...

Comment: It does to explicit transactions but only across methods like save and update_attributes.  So your after_save will run in the same transaction.

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest about deadlocks, sometimes you can re-order things to avoid them.  There are a few plugins for retrying on deadlocks (http://github.com/rails/deadlock_retry).  Might be worth looking at those too.

Answer (score 1):

Rollback not be processed.

ex:

```
create_table "helps", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "title",                           :null => false
    t.text     "content"
end

#Rails console
Help.transaction do
  Help.create! title: "aaa"
  begin
    Help.create! content: "111"
  rescue
    p "create error."
  end
  Help.create! title: "bbb"
end

#get this
>> "create error."
Help.count
>> 2
```

Answer (score -4):

You can also try my answer for rollback, catch and rendering for your create method using **ActiveRecord::Base.transaction**:-
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23104039/1388654)

Thanks