# Render failing to render correct template in rescue_from ActiveRecord::Rollback method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, transactions, rails-activerecord

I'm building the checkout page for an e-commerce site, and I have a fairly long transaction that creates a new User model and a new Order model. I wrapped the creation of these models in a transaction so that if validation for one fails, the other isn't hanging around in the database. Here's the trimmed-down code in my OrdersController:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::Rollback, with: :render_new

def render_new
  render action: 'new'
end

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  @user = User.new params[:user]
  unless @user.save
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
  //More stuff
  ...
  @order = Order.new params[:order]
  ...
  unless @order.save
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
  end
end
```

The error I'm seeing is this:

> Missing template orders/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}

I'm confused as to why its trying to render the templates orders/create and application/create instead of rendering orders/new.

Is there a better way to force the transaction to fail so that the rollback will occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the intention is a bit clearer when wrapping the transaction in a begin/rescue block.

```
def create
  begin 
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @user = User.new params[:user]
      unless @user.save
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
      //More stuff
      ...
      @order = Order.new params[:order]
      ...
      unless @order.save
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback
    render action: "new" and return
  end
end
```

You need to **return** in the `create` method, otherwise it's execution will continue to the end of the method and Rails default render will occur *(in this case it means attempting to find a `create.___` template)*.

If you don't like the begin/rescue block you can just add an `and return` to the `raise` lines

```
raise ActiveRecord::Rollback and return
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, I still haven't had any success. I introduced a begin/rescue block around my transaction as you suggested, but for some reason the rescue block is never getting executed. I even switched to a more generic exception for the rescue block, ActiveRecordError, and the block still did not get executed. Can you think of any reasons why this would happen, especially when I am explicitly raising an ActiveRecordError exception?

Answer (score 2):

Above answer is correct but some modification is required for rendering action.

Do it like this:-

```
def create
    is_project_saved = false
    is_proposal_saved = false

    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      is_project_saved = @project.save
      is_proposal_saved = @proposal.save
      if is_project_saved && is_proposal_saved
        # Do nothing
      else
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    end

    if is_project_saved && is_proposal_saved
      # You can add more nested conditions as per you need.
      flash[:notice] = "Proposal Created Successfully."
      redirect_to project_show_path(:job_id => @project.job_id)
    else
      render :new
    end
end
```

**ActiveRecord::Rollback** will not be caught by resque. So it needs to be done outside transaction block.

You can also use save_point using `:requires_new => true` in nested `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to raise the ActiveRecord::Rollback and manage the render/redirect as you desire. As @WasimKhan said, the ActiveRecord::Rollback will not be caught by rescue.

```
def create
  @user = User.new params[:user]
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    if @user.save
      @order = Order.new params[:order]
      if @order.save
        redirect_to :index
      else
        raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
      end
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
  render :new if @user.id.nil?
end
```